# Line fitting for stair detection using OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, object-detection

I'm trying to fit lines from an binary image below. My main objective is to detect a stair model. Is there any way to do this in OpenCV ? 
[image]
Thank for your help.

Comment: Add also the original image, the code you tried, actual results and expexted results. You said HT didn't work, can you show why to us?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest methods I can think of are either the [Hough Transform](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d10/tutorial_py_houghlines.html) (`HoughLines()` for lines and `HoughLinesP()` for segments) or RANSAC (I couldn't find a RANSAC line detector in OpenCV. However there are interesting implementations in the [MRPT](http://www.mrpt.org/tutorials/programming/maths-and-geometry/ransac-c-examples/) and [PCL](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/random_sample_consensus.php)).

**EDIT**: A method based on `Canny()` and `HoughLines()` is explained in [extract lines from canny edge detection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10902423/865719)

Answer (score 1):

Thank Miki, 865719 , Photon, and Humam Helfawi,

After using Hough-Transform, I see that the result is not good. You can see in Figure below:
[image: hough transform result]

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
Mat src, dst, color_dst;
src=imread("stairs.png");

Canny( src, dst, 50, 200, 3 );
cvtColor( dst, color_dst, CV_GRAY2BGR );


vector<Vec4i> lines;
HoughLinesP( dst, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 80, 30, 10 );
for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
{
    line( color_dst, Point(lines[i][0], lines[i][1]),
        Point(lines[i][2], lines[i][3]), Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8 );
}


namedWindow( "Source", 1 );
imshow( "Source", src );

namedWindow( "Detected Lines", 1 );
imshow( "Detected Lines", color_dst );

waitKey(0);
return 0;}
```

Thank for your support.

Hieu.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the lines in the image by using the hough transform.

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html

(The question is not detailed enough for more.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in this case, Hough Transform is not effective.

Comment: You will have to describe what you're trying to accomplish with more detail then.

Answer (score 0):

Get the contours  of your images and apply the hough-transform on the contours.
you will got some duplicate line (very near to each other).. just filter them on some distance criteria

Comment: Canny is option too instead of the contours.

Comment: Humam Helfawi, I don't understand how to filter based on some distance criteria. ?